# dynamic height alignment in constraintlayout

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have 3 textview in which the text can change dynamically, I need to make them equal to each other, whose height is greater than that height and take for all. I'm trying using barriers but don't get positive result, also i try set all textviews height 0dp but all textviews then disappeared, i can set the height for one textview wrap_content and for another 0dp but then they will be equal only in the first textview. When I used linearlayout I did it, but with constraintlayout i don't understand how do it.
[image]

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="1234567"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/coefficient_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/coefficient_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 2"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/label_zone1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="1234567"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/coefficient_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/coefficient_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 3"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/label_zone2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="12345678"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/coefficient_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/coefficient_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="coefficient_zone1,coefficient_zone2,coefficient_zone3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="consumption_zone1,consumption_zone2,consumption_zone3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_calculated_indicators"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="title title title title"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/consumption_zone1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There are many questions like yours in SO where a barrier based on dynamically changing views is required, but none of them provide an answer using only ConstraintLayout. They either nest a LinearLayout or use an invisible helper view as a reference. I'd be interested in seeing a solid solution that respects the flatness of ConstraintLayout and it doesn't seem like a hack-ey workaround at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nikos Hidalgo stated in the comment to your question, this is a common question that is asked on Stack Overflow. I have come across four ways to accomplish a common width and/or common height for a set of views. Unfortunately, none is ideal.

Here is a screen shot showing the three of the four ways to get to common dimensions. The XML for this screen is at the end of this post.

[image]

**Embedded LinearLayout**

This is probably the easiest way. Place the *TextViews* in a horizontal *LinearLayout* setting their heights to *MATCH_PARENT*. Set the height of the *LinearLayout* to *WRAP_CONTENT* and all will work out. The benefit of this way is its simplicity. Negatives include the overhead of a nested layout and the inability for any of the views within the *LinearLayout* to be connected to any view outside the *LinearLayout* - they become an island.

**Invisible Views**

This is probably the most complicated way of doing things but it may be OK depending upon the layout. The basic problem with setting up barriers to adjust the height of a set of views is that the barrier placement depends upon the height of the views and the height of the views depend upon the barrier placement. This is a referential quandary and does not work with the current version of *ConstraintLayout*.

The *invisible view* solution is to duplicate the views for which height is to be adjusted as invisible views. Set a top and a bottom barrier to these invisible views. Set the height of the visible views to *MATCH_CONSTRAINTS* and connect the tops to the top barrier and the bottom to the bottom barrier.

The benefit of this approach is that it is totally flat and involves just the *ConstraintLayout*. The drawbacks are that it increases the view count by the number of views to be adjusted, its complexity and everything that complexity entails.

**Constraint Layout Size Helper**

The third approach is to use a custom [ConstraintHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/helper/package-summary) to change the heights of the views. The custom *ConstraintHelper* is inserted into the XML for the layout like any other view and made to reference the views to be adjusted.

The benefit of this approach is that the changes are all kept within the XML. The negative is that a custom class must be referenced and maintained.

**Listener to Update Width/Height**

This final approach is to custom code the height adjustments using a global layout listener, a layout listener or the like. This is similar to the *ConstraintHelper* approach but exists outside of the XML and may not be well encapsulated.

It might also be possible to code custom views to set heights of views to the greatest height either with a custom *ConstraintLayout* or a custom *TextView*.

**Sample Layout**

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Embedded LinearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView3_0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2_0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is the TextView that has the maximum height."
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Invisible Views"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView3_2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout2"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3_2"
            tools:visibility="invisible"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView5_0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView3_0"
            tools:visibility="invisible"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is the TextView that has the maximum height."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3_2"
            tools:visibility="invisible"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrierTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="top"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView3_1,textView3_2,textView3_3" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrierBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="bottom"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView3_1,textView3_2,textView3_3" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrierBottom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrierTop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrierBottom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrierTop"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrierBottom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrierTop"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is the TextView that has the maximum height."
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrierBottom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrierTop"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="ConstraintLayout Size Helper"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrierBottom"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView5_1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView5_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView5_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5_2"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView5_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5_0"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is the TextView that has the maximum height."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5_2"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <com.example.constraintsizehelper.ConstraintSizeHelper
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView5_1,textView5_2,textView5_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:setCommonWidth="true"
            app:setCommonHeight="true"
            tools:layout_height="120dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is a reduced version of your layout using a Constraint Size Helper class (not provided):

[image]

And its XML:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_border"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/coefficient_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/coefficient_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 2"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/label_zone1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_border"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="12345678"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/coefficient_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/coefficient_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 3"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/label_zone2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_border"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="1234567890"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/coefficient_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/coefficient_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="coefficient_zone1,coefficient_zone2,coefficient_zone3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="consumption_zone1,consumption_zone2,consumption_zone3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_calculated_indicators"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="title title title title"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/consumption_zone1" />

    <com.example.myapplication.ConstraintSizeHelper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_height="120dp"
        app:setCommonWidth="false"
        app:setCommonHeight="true"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="consumption_zone1,consumption_zone2,consumption_zone3"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I choose old school variant with linearlayout, but I do not understand why google did not think through this moment

Comment: @mario I think that is an entirely reasonable approach.

Comment: I believe this answer should mention that a ContraintHelper doing that is provided by Google: Flow (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow)

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierDybman I wasn't aware of that. Since this is such a common question, others may find it helpful if you write an answer to this question with that solution.

Comment: @Cheticamp I'm sorry, I've been lied to: I tried to solve OP's use case with Flow and I failed. Flow does very good thing but unlike some blog posts claim, it's not the answer to flexbox and stuff.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierDybman I have come to the conclusion that it can't be done with Flow and and XML-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

> As per I understand your question try to use horizontal chain for "consumption_zone" all textviews.

[image: Blockquote]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 2"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/label_zone1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coefficient_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text="
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_zone3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test 3"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/label_zone2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="coefficient_zone1,coefficient_zone2,coefficient_zone3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/consumption_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/consumption_zone3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/consumption_zone1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consumption_zone3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/consumption_zone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="consumption_zone1,consumption_zone2,consumption_zone3" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: add to consumption_zones border for clarity and add in one textview two line text and one line text to others. your example doesn't work